# Log4Net/C# - Disable default logging

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net in a C# project, in the production environment, I want to disable all the logging, but when some fatal 
error occures it should log all the previous 512 messages in to a file.I have successfully configured this, and it is working fine. It logs the messages in to a file when some fatal error occures.

But when I run it from Visual Studio, I can see all the log messages are written to the Output window, regardless of whether it is a Fatal or not. (I cant see these messages when I run from the Windows Explorer - my application is a WinForm exe and there is no Console window to see the output)

Is there any way to disable this logging? I need my logs only in file, that too when some fatal error occures.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <log4net debug="false">

        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="log.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="BufferingForwardingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender" >
            <bufferSize value="512" />
            <lossy value="true" />
            <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
                <threshold value="FATAL"/>
            </evaluator>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
        </appender> 

        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="BufferingForwardingAppender" />          
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

And this is how I configure it in the static initializer of Windows Forms.

```
static Window1()
    {
      Stream vStream = typeof(Window1).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestLogNet.log4net.config");
      XmlConfigurator.Configure(vStream);
      BasicConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

And I have the logger object initialized in the constructor of WinForm

```
logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Window1));
```

[language - C#,
.NET Framework - 3.5,
Visual Studio 2008,
log4net 1.2.10,
project type - WinForms]

Comment: does it matter that everything is being output to the console? surely since there is no console o your winforms app it's just logging as you want it to?

Comment: It matters for performance, since all console calls are synchronized. If you've got a bunch of background threads doing logging then they'll suffer badly.

Comment: +1 for the complete details regarding the problem (there are too many questions that can be resumed to "help, it's not working")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the [BasicConfigurator.Configure()](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure_overload_1.html) line.  That's what that line does -- adds a ConsoleAppender pointing to Console.Out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still see the messages in Visual Studio if the application is compiled in release mode? It's possible that log4net uses Debug.Write to show the errors anyway. If that's the case then those messages shouldn't appear in release mode.